# Bootstrap 3 style editors

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Are there any style editors (such as [Bootstrap Themeroller](http://www.bootstrapthemeroller.com/)) that support Bootstrap 3 yet?

Comment: AFAIK The only Bootstrap tool that currently supports 3 is Bootply (http://bootply.com) -- but it doesn't specifically support styling.

Comment: check out '18 bootsrap UI editors' (http://mashable.com/2013/10/20/bootstrap-editors/)

Answer (score 2):

Try this [Bootstrap-Magic](http://pikock.github.io/bootstrap-magic/), i was used this app for customize some bootstrap variables like `border-radius`, colors, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you will find these useful however they might require signup to create a custom one
http://bootstrap3.kissr.com/

https://wrapbootstrap.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can try to customize colors, fonts, layouts etc using [bootstrap customizer](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) itself. If you're familiar with LESS, you can download the less files from the github repository and compile the less file using a less editor/compiler apps such as [crunch](http://crunchapp.net/) or [winless](http://winless.org/) after customizing styles variables.

Answer (score 0):

No 'ThemeRoller' for V3 yet.

I just use the current one at http://www.bootstrapthemeroller.com/twitter-bootstrap-themeroller.html
Then make your adjustments and download the files. Use bootstrap.css only.

Go to http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#migration and rename classes in the downloaded css as pointed out on that page.
Example: **.muted** becomes **.text-muted**

Comment: Unfortunately this project seems to be dead.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can customize layouts,colors, fonts, etc using drag and drop facility.  [Layout It](http://www.layoutit.com/) . and you can download it in all formats like normal CSS , Less or Saas.

i think its a great site for making good layout . you can also select some of the pre-built templates to customize them and download them.

Comment: This looks like a pretty nice tool for laying out a page, but it doesn't pertaining to editing or creating a the Bootstrap theme.

Answer (score 0):

Although it's limited as far as saving, importing, and exporting, [BootSwatchr](http://bootswatchr.com) has been useful to me for previewing settings before doing a custom download from the official Bootstrap site.

Answer (score 0):

I just created the [Bootstrap ThemeRoller](https://www.bootpress.org/themeroller/) that allows you to edit the variables.less file, and create a custom/theme.less file so you can just copy and paste what you have (or a Bootswatch theme), and make any changes you like.  When you click on a hex or rgb(a) value we also display a colorpicker that you can use to see what color you have, and easily modify it as well.